# 100GB of system data

Tags: iphone, ios, storage

I was trying to update my iPhone with iOS 14.1
I was told that I didn't have enough storage left, I was very surprised since I'm using about 10 of my 128 gigabytes available

After investigation, it appears that the 114GB is used for "other system data", which seems absurd.

How to free up this space? (I guess most of it is irrelevant)

[image]

Comment: Does the space used change after a reboot of the iPad?

Comment: It is an iPhone not an iPad but the space is indeed the same after reboot

Answer (score 2):

If possible, try deleting an app or two (optimally, one with some data stored on the iPhone) and see if this changes. If it goes *up*, this could be a "known" bug, in which case the only solution I'm aware of is, sadly, the nuclear option....  wipe the iPhone from Settings, and restore from backup (make sure to backup first!).

Answer (score 1):

After saving some space to download the update and installing it, the bug has been fixed.

Only 9GB are used in this category.